# Angular.js datasource with variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I run the following code, "users" is outputed to console correctly, but it seems $scope.users is not defined when used in the datasource. In the datasource if I replace $scope.users with a number then it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/users'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.users = response.data.users;                                
            console.log($scope.users);
        },
        function (response) {
            console.log("Error: "+ response.data.result);
        })

        $scope.activeUsers = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: [
                {
                    "status": "user alive",
                    "numUsers": $scope.users,
                    "statusColor": "#dc3c3f"                        
                }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely because your `$scope.activeUsers` is being defined before your `$http` request has completed. Try the following

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/users'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.users = response.data.users;                                
        console.log($scope.users);
        $scope.activeUsers = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          data: [
            {
                "status": "user alive",
                "numUsers": $scope.users,
                "statusColor": "#dc3c3f"                        
            }
          ]
        });
    },
    function (response) {
        console.log("Error: "+ response.data.result);
    })
```

Comment: well, going to write exactly the same thing... you should read some doc about `promises`. Angular uses them a lot.

Comment: Agreed - get out of callback hell 